# Releasing in ASP.Net to Production

Tags: asp.net, deployment, release

I recently got a new computer and forgot how to create a Release for my asp.net app.  I need to generate a Release folder in the Solution Explorer. I've changed the build from Debug to Relase. What am I missing?

Comment: did you do a build after switching build from Debug to Release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, ASP.NET applications place code directly to the `bin` directory (there won't be Debug or Release directories) when built. So, if you changed the configuration to Release, you should be ready to go.

**Edit:** If you need your assemblies to be output to a *Release* folder below your *bin* folder, then open your web app's project properties, click the *Build tab*, and change the *Output Path* setting from **bin** to **bin\Release**.

Comment: true but that's not how our app is set up. I need to have it emit to a Release folder.

Comment: @chris Ah, okay, then change the `Output Path` folder to `bin\Release` under the *Build* project properties tab.

Comment: is that under property pages?

Comment: I have it as MSBuild property and set the output path to C:\Release4 but that folder doesn't appear in my solution explorer or on my C drive.

Comment: i am using vs 2008 pro edtion btw

Comment: Try changing the *Output Path* build setting in Visual Studio to C:\Release4 and perform a Release build from the IDE.  Ideally, your files will be deployed there.  Does that work?

Comment: the build happens instantaneouly but yet it appears that nothing is being done. on my previous computer i think the release folders were .wdproj projects(?).

Comment: The ISO that I got from MS, might not have had the ability to create Web Deployment Projects which I just downloaded and will be testing now, and I'll let you know.

Comment: That's something completely different. You must have had a web deployment project created to package and deploy your web app. Do you have that project anymore? If not, you're going to have to create a new one and configure it to deploy your app to your server.

Comment: Yeah that is correct.  I'm checking to see if I still have that project. Thanks a bunch.